# Tornado 3.2 OverflowError: can't convert negative int to unsigned

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I'm running my `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase` based testcases and occasionally see this stacktrace in the log. It appears to happen randomly so running the test suite multiple times just sometimes run into this behaviour.

Is this a [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) 3.2 bug or am I supposed to handle this Exception some how?

It doesn't appear to affect any of my test results, but I'm not too happy about random exceptions being left like this.

```
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.wrapped at 0x10727d830>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 477, in _run_callback
    callback()
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 331, in wrapped
    raise_exc_info(exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 366, in wrapper
    self._maybe_add_error_listener()
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 600, in _maybe_add_error_listener
    self._add_io_state(ioloop.IOLoop.READ)
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/iostream.py", line 630, in _add_io_state
    self.fileno(), self._handle_events, self._state)
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 545, in add_handler
    self._impl.register(fd, events | self.ERROR)
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/platform/kqueue.py", line 41, in register
    self._control(fd, events, select.KQ_EV_ADD)
  File "/Users/fredrik/.virtualenvs/project/lib/python3.3/site-packages/tornado/platform/kqueue.py", line 60, in _control
    fd, filter=select.KQ_FILTER_READ, flags=flags))
OverflowError: can't convert negative int to unsigned
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen this before, but it looks like a socket object has been closed (changing its file descriptor to -1) while an IOStream is still trying to read from it.  Are you doing any unusual cleanup in your tests or reaching into any IOStreams to access the socket object directly?

Comment: No fancy IOStream stuff that I can see. And if so, I would expect the OverflowError to be raised every time I run the test suit. Now it's like once every 30th time.

Comment: Hmm.  Could you try installing Tornado from the master branch on github?  There were some issues around sockets getting closed by garbage collection that were fixed after 3.2 was released.  I don't quite see how they'd lead to this symptom (since they wouldn't get garbage collected if the IOSteram is still using them), but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've checked out the latest on tornado master but still the same problem. I'll spend some time to see if I can locate what tests are causing this.